# HttpWebRequest to Okta result in Forbidden 403

Tags: httpwebrequest, webrequest, okta, okta-api

I'm currently stumble on frustrating Forbidden 403 error when doing simple GET WebRequest to Okta. I've added my application url into Okta Admin > Security > API as CORS. Below is my code

```
string requestURL = "https://myokta.oktapreview.com/api/v1/users/me";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(requestURL);
request.Method = "GET";
request.Timeout = 120000;
request.ContentType = "application/json";
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse(); // exception Forbidden 403
```

I could copy paste the requestURL in internet browser and get the json response without any problem. And if I don't have session, it also return error code E0000005 - Invalid session.

If I cannot do it through WebRequest, any suggestion on which client to use in okta.core.dll ?

Please help me and any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you ...

Comment: May I ask what your use case is here? It looks like you are trying to make that call from the server code of your web application. However, that specific /api/v1/users/me operation is only intended to be used on the browser channel (such as a JavaScript call) and needs to use a session cookie tied to your Okta domain (normally set to your browser session when you authenticate with Okta). If your user is already authenticated with your web app, your web app should have access to an http context in order to know who the current user is. Is that not the case?

Comment: The use case is we have two separated solutions for web client and web api. In web api, it has Authorize attribute and web api does not know / get the ClaimsIdentity from the wsfed web client.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the info. There isn't any out-of-the-box solution for your use case, but I would strongly suggest that you switch to OpenID Connect. I have a .NET sample with a Single Page Application and a web API that demonstrates how you can deserialize the JWT token in the Web API to retrieve the user's identity. You can find at https://github.com/rlondner/okta-aspnet-spa_webapi-oidc/

Answer (score 0):

When enabling CORS, please make sure that you type out the correct url.
For instance if you are running https locally, 'http://localhost:8080/' would be the correct url to enable. You also have to enable 'https://developer.okta.com' in Okta's developer console.